Best practices for usability tests that need to simulate customers?
I'm testing a till system soon and I'm curious about the best way to do so.
I feel like the best way to get insights would be to write tasks as if I'm a customer asking the participants for products, rather than the usual method of asking them to complete a task.
For example, instead of "Please add the following products" I'd say something like "Hi, I would like X and X please. Can I pay by card?".
Does anyone have any best practice advice on conducting tests like this? Thanks!

There are two aspects to the writing of tasks for the usability tests, one that relates to being able to have a clear idea of the coverage of the tests (against features that need to be tested), and the other that relates to how well the tasks can be understood by the users and carried out (it's almost like a usability test of your usability test).
In relation to the first point, the best way to ensure that you have complete coverage in your testing is to create a clear and standardized way of mapping the tasks to the features, and that paths like the most frequently used, ideal or worst case scenarios are thoroughly tested.
As for the second point, it can help improve the outcomes in your test results if you use natural language to specify the test, but it does make things more difficult when you have to map it back to your test plan to ensure complete test coverage.
So I would suggest that you start by working out how you would satisfy point one, and then tweak the content so that it can satisfy point two to the degree that you need it to.

Thank you! I was already taking this approach, so it's nice to have it validated as correct. It's much appreciated!

There are also some general tips for writing usability testing tasks from nng that you can reference: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/task-scenarios-usability-testing/ and https://www.nngroup.com/articles/better-usability-tasks/
